# Excel Datarange of 1 column across seperate sheets for column chart

Tags: excel

So I have an excel with multiple tabs/sheets each representing a month, so i.e. August 2011, September 2011 etc.

On each sheet I have some data figures, and one important figure which is in Table column "D5" on every sheet.

What I am trying to do is create a new tab/sheet called summary, on and on this sheet have a column chart which represents this "D5" figure for each month.

How can I write the data range in excel for chart to get this figure on all sheets ?

Comment: You're probably thinking about [3D references](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-3-d-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-HP010102346.aspx), but they don't work as a source for a chart.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in two steps:

1. In a new worksheet: a) in column A (say, starting with cell A1) list the names of the monthly worksheets (so, with `August 2011` in cell A1, `September 2011` in cell A2, and so on), b) in the first row of column B (say, cell B1), enter the formula `=INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!D5"), and, c) copy the formula from cell B1 down to the other rows in column B.
2. Create a chart based on columns A and B in the new worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'named ranges' to name each cell in a simple format.

Name Cell D5 on each sheet:

- 'January 2011'!D5 = IMPORTANT_JAN_2011
- 'February 2011'!D5 = IMPORTANT_FEB_2011
- etc.

Then on the summary enter the following as the formula in the range(s) you want the data, for example
=IMPORTANT_JAN_2011
=IMPORTANT_FEB_2011